# FindIsomers produces disconnected fragments

Tags: core-language, chemistry, education

I was playing around with FindIsomers and got this strange result,

```
FindIsomers[Molecule["butane"]]
```

output
[image: output of FindIsomers]

This seems unexpected in the sense that you wouldn't expect fragments to be considered isomers. Is this behavior normal?

My version is "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Comment: I don't think this behavior is correct (those fragments are not constitutional isomers of butane by any definition I know) but then again, `FindIsomers` is still marked as experimental, and it relies on external data lookup rather than calculation, so its results may be only as good as the quality of the input data after filtering / cleanup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree this is not desirable behavior, but by default `FindIsomers` will search PubChem for isomers and PubChem does not restrict disconnected structures.  See https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/159343502 for example.

[`FindIsomers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIsomers.html) has 2 undocumented options, `{"IncludeDisconnected" -> True, "IncludeIsotopes" -> False}`, so this works:

```
In[34]:= FindIsomers[Molecule["butane"], "IncludeDisconnected" -> False] 

Out[34]//OutputForm= {Molecule[<C4H10>], Molecule[<C4H10>]}
```

It is also possible to restrict FindIsomers to only return chemical entities:

```
In[4]:= FindIsomers[Molecule["butane"], "Entity"]

Out[4]= {Entity["Chemical", "2Methylpropane"], Entity["Chemical", "Butane"]}
```

This is a good time to link to the recently published [IsomerGeneration](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/IsomerGeneration/) paclet, which will generate all structural isomers from a given chemical formula without database lookup.

```
In[1]:= PacletInstall["WolframChemistry/IsomerGeneration"]

Out[1]= PacletObject[<|...|>]

In[2]:= Needs["WolframChemistry`IsomerGeneration`"]

In[3]:= IsomerList[Molecule["butane"]]

Out[3]= {"CC(C)C", "CCCC"}
```

The paclet was just published recently, and has a decent amount of documentation. Please let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Hi Jason! Yes, this is very useful. I'm currently experimenting with a genetic algorithm-inspired approach to finding "optimal" molecules with respect to certain properties (e.g., the partition coefficient between octanol and water). One has to be careful in doing this, because from generation to generation the population can easily explode.... So it might be useful to exclude further substructures in advance (peroxides, Erlenmeyer forbidden motifs etc.) in addition to the nine "built-in" restrictions via "ForbiddenSubstructures" option. Anyway, fantastic work!

Comment: Second, small hint, but maybe useful for others: I had to uninstall the paclet in V13.3, and then request it again via PacletInstall[...] because Mathematica was giving error messages, "couldn't find RDKit" or something. Is this a common behavior for Paclets from the PacletRepository, when new Mathematica versions are installed?